# Mongodb C# Driver Unsupported filter error with specific linq predicate

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a IMongoCollection  of contents:

```
collection = [
{Value = 'x', EntryPoint= 'ROOT/1' }, 
{Value = 'y', EntryPoint= 'ROOT/2' }, 
{Value = 'z', EntryPoint= 'OTHER/1' }]
```

now I want to filter my collections with ​
`userEntryPoints = ['ROOT', 'SPECIAL']`.

We defined, if I have `entrypoint = 'ROOT'`, it is equivalant that we have entrypoint of `'ROOT/1', 'ROOT2'` too.

So the expected result is

```
result = [
{Value = 'x', EntryPoint= 'ROOT/1' }, 
{Value = 'y', EntryPoint= 'ROOT/2' }]
```

The code I am using is

```
var collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection(Data);
return collection.AsQueryable().Select(xxx)
.Where(item => userEntryPoints.Any( entrypoint => item.EntryPoint.StartsWith(entrypoint)))
```

This should work if `collection` and `userEntryPoints` are simple array.

But in my code, at runtime I have a mongodb error:

```
Unsupported filter: Any(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]].Where({document}{EntryPoint}.StarsWith(document))))

At MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Traslators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
```

What can I do to make such filtering possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked to return the two matching documents:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^ROOT|^SPECIAL");
var qry = collection.AsQueryable()
                    .Where<CollectonClass>(e => regex.IsMatch(e.EntryPoint))
                    .Select(e => new { e.Value, e.EntryPoint } );

var docList = qry.ToList();
docList.ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine(e.ToJson()));
```

A variation:

```
var rgxList = new string [] { "^ROOT", "^SPECIAL" };
var rgx = new Regex(string.Join("|", rgxList));
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("EntryPoint", rgx);
var list = collection.Find(filter).ToList<BsonDocument>();
```

Comment: good one with the or regex. didn't know the driver could translate that. cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that with the driver. it doesn't translate the `StartsWith`. it would only work with a simple equality check. here's how to get the result you want. you need to convert your input to an array of prefixed regexes. unfortunately there's no strongly typed way to do it.

```cs
var userEntryPoints = "[/^ROOT/,/^SPECIAL/]";

FilterDefinition<Content> filter = $"{{ EntryPoint : {{ $in : {userEntryPoints} }} }}";

var result = await (await collection.FindAsync(filter)).ToListAsync();
```