# MongoDB BsonRegularExpression on 3 levels down array Works on shell but not on .Net Core

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple query that works fine on Studio 3T or Mongo Shell, but on .Net Core (driver 2.11.3) does not.

My Collection is like this:

[image]

Works (Studio 3T / Mongo Shell):

```
db.getCollection("AssetBundle").find({ "Variations.Assets.Asset" : /.*ptk.*/i })
```

Does not work (.Net):

```
PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
            {
                new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument()
                        .Add("Variations.Assets.Asset", new BsonRegularExpression(".*ptk.*", "i")))
            };
            
            using (var cursor = await collection.AggregateAsync(pipeline, options))
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    var batch = cursor.Current;
                    foreach (BsonDocument document in batch)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
                    }
                }
            }
```

I can change the regex but does not work too::

```
new BsonRegularExpression("ptk", "i")
```

Comment: You are using _find_ method in `mongo` shell and an _aggregate_ method in C#. Why?

Comment: This was only to ilustrate, in the end, will be a big Aggregation and in Robo3T the Aggregations  generate the code (mongo shell, c#, node, etc...). I think thr problem is with BsonRegularExpression that in c# does not work exactly as a normal Regex...

Comment: See this recent post with regex and C# MongoDB Driver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67108879/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-unsupported-filter-error-with-specific-linq-predicate/67114011#67114011